# How to set Default Constraint for top 100 or 5 rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this possible to add constraint, like the one below, using this method?

I am getting an error.

```
ALTER TABLE students 
ADD CONSTRAINT Adding_Default_Date
    DEFAULT 1 FOR (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM students);
```

Comment: What is your main goal here? Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The **default constraint** is a table-based constraint that defines a default value for a column - it's not something you can apply to a query result from a `SELECT` - not sure what you're really trying to do here.... please provide more information

Comment: Added the SQL Server tag `TOP 5` suggest using SQL Server.. Faraz Khan for good answers we need example data and expected results.. I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: No, this is not possible.  If you tried to run this code, you would get an error.  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, Check constraints only apply to individual rows.

Also, a Default constraints cannot access other rows.

It is not entirely clear from your description what you are trying to achieve.

If you want a Default constraint, but with your own custom logic, you might be able to achieve your goal with a Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Adding_Default_Date ON students
AFTER INSERT
AS Begin
  UPDATE s
  SET my_column = ...
  FROM student AS s
  JOIN inserted AS i
    ON i.key = s.key
End
```